# Is it possible to make querySelectorAll live like getElementsByTagName?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, getelementsbytagname, selectors-api

`getElementsByTagName()` has 2 great features: it is fast and it is live. But what if I want to get `p strong`. Of course I could refine a selection using `getElementsByTagName()` again but wouldn't I lose the live effect for the new `p` tags?

Is there a way to turn `querySelectorAll` into a live selector?

Or... is there a way to use `getElementsByTagName()` and `getElementsByClassName()` to create a function that works in a similar way (at least with descendants) as `querySelectorAll` but being live?

Comment: Such a feature, if implemented natively, would probably be excluded from the dynamic profile, preventing level 4 selectors like `:has()` with complex selectors from being used, as live selector matching is basically what happens in CSS and as such is performance-sensitive. Still, I'm curious to know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider using mutation observers. Watch for `childList` with `subtree: true`. When the notification arrives, you can examine each added node with `matches` to see if it matches some selector.

```
function querySelectorAllLive(element, selector) {

  // Initialize results with current nodes.
  var result = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.querySelectorAll(selector));

  // Create observer instance.
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      [].forEach.call(mutation.addedNodes, function(node) {
        if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.matches(selector)) {
          result.push(node);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  // Set up observer.
  observer.observe(element, { childList: true, subtree: true });

  return result;
}
```

Comment: this is looking good but I'm getting an error on target.matches. Did you try this? I just created a pen: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/Nqpxww?editors=101

Comment: Sorry, it should be `observer.observe(element`.

Comment: And it is `subtree` not `subTree`. Now it works. Sorry.

Comment: No errors now, but when I press gimme! I don't get the new elements... Could you check the pen again?

Comment: Oh my. It really looks like I have to test my code better. See fixes.

Comment: I don't understand how this notifies you when a new element has been added to the array, you would have to check it on a timer or something. I think this could work better with a callback that is called when items are added to the array.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible because subsequent changes of the DOM does not reflect in the NodeList object returned by the querySelectorAll() method.

[Selectors-api W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall)